# Synchronization Javascript problem + Rails + Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have my two `javascript_pack_tag` helper in *application.html.erb*

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
```

In *application.js* I have my vue js script and in *home.js* I have my custom script who make simply

```
new Vue({

el: '#app',
data: { hello: "hello" }

});
```

but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor` into my console browser I think have a synchronization problem, because when I run the same code of my *home.js* directly in the console that work

Edit.

In packs/js/home-244ef5bb5ce4f58d96da.js I have :

```
/***/ "./app/javascript/packs/home.js":
/*!*****************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/javascript/packs/home.js ***!
  \*****************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(Vue) {
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { hello: "hello"}
});
```

Comment: Check your manifest to see if that code is in there.  Should be in view source, maybe it's not getting the code, and order really matters with JS

Comment: Please post the contents of application.js and home.js